# Laravel Service Provider: new class with params

Tags: laravel, service-provider

is it possible to pass parameters to a class inside app()->make in bind?

// **MyServiceProvider.php (extends ServiceProvider)**

```
$this->app->bind('MyService', function ($app) {
   return new MyService(
      $app->make('Carbon'),
      $app->make('SendGrid') // here is where i want to pass some parameters like if I do: new SendGrid($apiKey)
   )
});
```

I have try makeWith but still i got this error: 
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  $apiKey ]] in class SendGrid

```
$this->app->bind('MyService', function ($app) {
   return new MyService(
      $app->make('Carbon'),
      $app->makeWith('SendGrid', ['apiKey' => '123'])
   )
});
```

How can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
First you have to register a service provider with sendgrid and THEN add the sendgrid service provider in the MyServiceProvider.php.